# Not able to take "name "as input

Tags: c++, vector, input, switch-statement, getline

I think there's some kind of type issue. Maybe I'm missing something. When i enter the choice as 1 I'm provided with "Enter the Name: Enter the Role: " not being able to take "name" as input. I've created a class "Professor" with data members as 3 vectors of type string and an "int count" along with three member functions as "Recruit", "DisplayInfo" and "Remove". I'm basically trying to build a data of college professors.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    #include<algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    class Professor
    {
    private:
        vector<string> Name;
        vector<string> Role;
        vector<string>Subject;
        static int count1;
    public:
        void Recruit()
        {
            string name,role,subject;
            cout<<"Enter the Name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            Name.push_back(name);

            cout<<"Enter the Role: ";
            getline(cin, role);
            Role.push_back(role);

            cout<<"Enter the Subject to be assigned: ";
            getline(cin, subject);
            Subject.push_back(subject);
            count1++;
        }
        void DisplayInfo()
        {
            //cout<<"\nName   Role   Subject\n";
            for(int i=0; i<count1; i++)
            {
                cout<<"Name: "<<Name[i]<<"\n";
                cout<<"Role: "<<Role[i]<<"\n";
                cout<<"Subject: "<<Subject[i]<<"\n";   
            }
            cout<<"\n\n";
        }
        void Remove()
        {
            string name, role, subject;
            cout<<"Enter the name of the Professor, his/her Role and the subject assigned to him/her: ";
            cin>>name>>role>>subject;
            for(int i=0; i<count1; i++)
            {
                if(Name[i]==name && Role[i]==role && Subject[i]==subject)
                {
                    vector<string>::iterator iter1 = find(Name.begin(), Name.end(), name);

                    if(iter1 == Name.end())
                    {
                        cout<<"";
                    }
                    else{
                        Name.erase(iter1);
                    }
                    vector<string>::iterator iter2 = find(Role.begin(), Role.end(), role);
                    if(iter2 == Role.end())
                    {
                        cout<<"";
                    }
                    else{
                        Role.erase(iter2);
                    }
                    vector<string>::iterator iter3 = find(Subject.begin(), Subject.end(), subject);
                    if(iter2 == Role.end())
                    {
                        cout<<"";
                    }
                    else{
                        Role.erase(iter2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    int Professor :: count1;

    int main()
    {
        Professor p;
        int choice;
        do{
            cout<<"You have the following Choices:\n";
            cout<<"1) Recruit a Professor\n";
            cout<<"2) Display the Information about Professors\n";
            cout<<"3) Remove a Professor\n";
            cout<<"4) Quit\n";
            cout<<"\n\nEnter the choice:";

            cin>>choice;/*This is where it occurs. Code for "Recruit" member function is defined in 
                         "Professor" class above.*/

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    p.Recruit();
                    break; 
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    p.DisplayInfo();
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    p.Remove();
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    cout<<"Sorry Wrong Choice!!\n";
                }
            }
        }while(choice!=4);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a correct answer to your question. Slightly off-topic but I'd recommend that you reorganise your code. It might make more sense to rename your "Professor" class the "University" class and then create a struct called "Professor" with the fields name, role and subject. That way you can have a single std::vector<Professor> object instead of having three different std::vector objects. As you have it right now it doesn't logically make sense to "create a professor" and a then use that professor to recruit professors and remove professors.

Comment: Also you don't need to have a static int count1 variable. If you want to get the number of professors you can call "name.size()", "role.size()", or "subject.size()" (they should all be the same size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi abhishek the problem is with getline . I would recommend you to read about use of getline now just add the following line in Recruit() function and your problem will be solved

```
    void Recruit()
    {
        string name,role,subject;
        cout<<"Enter the Name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cin.ignore();
        Name.push_back(name);

        cout<<"Enter the Role: ";
        getline(cin, role);
        cin.ignore();
        Role.push_back(role);

        cout<<"Enter the Subject to be assigned: ";
        getline(cin, subject);
        cin.ignore();
        Subject.push_back(subject);
        count1++;
    }
```

make it a habit to use cin.ignore after getline .
Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks...but it's still the same. I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: i was expecting you will pick the hint anyways i have edited my response try it . will work.

Comment: No, I did pick the hint and did the same thing as you did. But still it's not happening.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry...it is indeed working thanks for that. Actually I was working on Visual Studio and there might be some cache problem that it couldn't save. I tried the same on code blocks and it was working so I restarted visual studio.